# ibus-avro in Ubuntu 16.04 not working

Tags: ibus

I have applied the procedure to install ibus avro in my laptop. This could be installed, but it is not working. In Text Entry Settings there is no option for setting ibus avro. Need suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to point out, there is no 16.04 version [on the site](http://linux.omicronlab.com/) it only gives PPA for up to 14.04, you must use a PPA for your version of Ubuntu.

I found a 16.04 version [on git hub](https://github.com/maateen/avro/releases), here are the instructions

```
wget "https://github.com/ugcoder/avro/releases/download/v2.0/avro_2.0-1_all.deb"    
sudo dpkg -i avro_2.0-1_all.deb
```

To resolve any missing dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install -fy
```

Go to System Settings -> Language Support from Unity Launcher
Look at the Keyboard input method system
Select IBus and close the window.

I believe that you need to restart IBus to make everything work fine. Try the following command:

```
ibus restart
```

Now go to System Settings -> Keyboard -> Text Entry.
Search and add Avro Phonetic as input source. That's all.

Comment: @ Mark Kirby - Thanks for your reply. The procedure was adopted earlier. But didn't yield any result. However, it is again applied, there is no desired effect. IBus has been selected at Keyboard input method system, but in Text Entry Avro Phonetic is not visible.